# Is it possible to turn off "seconds" and "long text in the end" for the "IntlDateFormatter::FULL" IntlDateFormatter date/time format?

Tags: php

*Note: Should this be considered the wrong Stack category, I shall ask you to kindly move it to the right one.*

***Example code:***

```
var_dump(IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime("2020-09-09 09:09:09 Europe/Madrid"), IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'es_ES'));
var_dump(IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime("2020-09-09 09:09:09 Europe/Madrid"), IntlDateFormatter::LONG, 'es_ES'));
```

***Output:***

```
string(79) "miércoles, 9 de septiembre de 2020, 9:09:09 (hora de verano de Europa central)"
string(37) "9 de septiembre de 2020, 9:09:09 CEST"
```

***I want output such as this:***

```
string(79) "miércoles, 9 de septiembre de 2020, 9:09"
```

That is, the "full" version (not "long" or any of the even shorter ones), just minus the second part as well as the "(hora de verano de Europa central)" in the end. I don't mean to str_replace or regexp it out, because that I already know how to do. I mean the correct, robust way to do this, so that it works for all the countless formats which output very different texts.

As far as I can tell, the various DateTime/NumberFormat/etc. classes/functions in PHP don't have such an option, but it has often happened in the past that it's just cleverly hidden somewhere where I didn't look.

Comment: What prevents you from constructing the date/time yourself using the date function and the format parameter?

Comment: Please read descriptions of tags before using them. Description of [php] would guide you to the right site.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate it with a regex

```
$date_str = IntlDateFormatter::formatObject(new DateTime("2020-09-09 09:09:09 Europe/Madrid"), IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'es_ES');
var_dump( preg_replace( '/:[0-9]{2} .*/', '', $date_str ) );
```